# When A + B are selected from two select lists, Load results page at #Anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an on-line store that has a product page. The page has two select boxes to choose from and will filter results based on those two options.

If I choose criteria A + B from the select boxes, the page filters through the products to show products with that criteria. However when this event happens, the page scrolls to the top of the page. This is especially annoying on mobile as the select boxes are not at the top of the page.

How can I add either a javascript event to scroll to a specific div (for example #ProductList) when the selection is made.

Or maybe an onload event that adds the #ProductList to the end of the url.

I have found examples to scroll to a div id based on the id selected. But I need something simpler that always scrolls to the same div #ProductList when the select boxes are clicked.

[This Example works for id selected but i need a general one that scrolls to one specific div id](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QD2xs/1/)

```
var select = document.getElementById('test');

select.onchange = function(){
var id = this.getElementsByTagName('option')[this.selectedIndex].value,
    el = document.getElementById(id),
    top = el.offsetTop;
window.scrollTo(0,top);
};
```

Any help is hugely appreciated!!!!

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use URL fragments to jump to the required page element. See the snippet below:

```
var select = document.getElementById('test');

select.onchange = function(){
    var id = this.getElementsByTagName('option')[this.selectedIndex].value;
    var link = window.location.href;

    // If URL already has a fragment, remove it
    if (link.indexOf('#') != -1)
        link = link.substring(0, link.indexOf('#'));

    // Add URL fragment with id of the div you want to jump to
    window.location.href = link + '#' + id;
};
```

Comment: That would most likely work! Where would this script need to be added? (Sorry i am very new to javascript)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Just use this code in place of your Javascript code snippet you used in your question. Check the jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/naveedaa/1kckq4wc/ for example

Comment: The example linked was a very basic shortened version of what i was trying to a achieve. Played around with my code and got it to work based on your suggestion! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
var id = 'YOUR ID HERE',
```

instead of

```
var id = this.getElementsByTagName('option')[this.selectedIndex].value,
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! This works perfectly for the example I linked. Implementing it to my live site isn't going so well however. My code i'm trying to edit contains a lot of php and mage (magento specific) code. Is there any chance I can get in contact with you with the full page code to see if you can help? I fear it's too much to indent into these comments

Comment: that would be possible but reading the comments above I guess yo already got it to work?

Comment: Yes I managed to in the end! Thank you again, is there any way I can reward more than one answer?

Answer (score 0):

what i would do is

```
$("#test").change(function(){
    var val=$(this).val();
    var divtext=""+$("#"+val+" p").html();// this is div content
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out!

Thanks for the different perspectives guys! Really helped me to stumble upon the answer!

You can delete/archive this post if needed. First time here so not sure on the protocol!

Thanks again

Frank